# How to keep "0" in double when use Math.Round in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to keep three decimal places for double type data, I use Math.Round() while the 0 at the end is omitted,how to keep it?

```
double? value = 0.3000;
double? result = Math.Round(value, 3);//get result = 0.3 while I need 0.300
```

I need `result` as type `double?` instead of `string`,so I cannot use `.ToString()`.

Anyting idea？

Comment: what is the difference between 0.3 and 0.300 when it is considered as of `double?` type? [.NET FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xa6dnm). Any specific reason for `0.300`

Comment: @Prasad Telkikar I just want to return api result as 0.300 and display it in frontend,since some result like 0.301 keep three decimal places,0.300 show 0.3,so I want to return three digits in a unified manner.

Comment: You can do it in javascript on frontend or what is problem to convert double to string using `0.3.ToString("0.000")`?

Comment: Read about IEEE floating point formats to get the details. For double, 3 and 3.000 are the exact same numbers. What you want is changing the display code like you would use “%.03f” in the C-style formatting functions. But I don’t know if something like that’s available in C# (I sure would think so).

Comment: @Prasad Telkikar Since model's field is of type double, I try to use  `.ToString("0.000")` but it has error. I will try in js then

Answer (score -1):

To do this, you need to change from double to decimal.